# The eigenstructure of the symmetric tridiagonal matrix whose entries are $a_{kk}=\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}$ and $$a_{1,2}=\cdots=a_{n-1,n}=1$$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, eigenvector

Suppose that  $A=(a_{kl})_{k,l=1}^n$ is a symmetric  tri-diagonal matix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ whose diagonal entries are $a_{kk}=\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}$ and
$$a_{1,2}=\cdots=a_{n-1,n}=1$$

Any approach to find the closed formula of eigenvectors?

Comment: This problem is not exactly solvable, see, for example https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02096501

Comment: In general, this is the same problem as solving a boundary value problem for the difference equation $u_{k+1}+u_{k-1} + a_{kk} u_k = zu_{kk}$. This will have explicit solutions only on very rare occasions, and even if it does, you haven't yet found the $z$'s satisfying the boundary conditions.

Comment: If I have this right, the diagonal entries of the matrix seem curiously equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ times the eigenvalues of the (Toeplitz) nondiagonal part.